# Bloomberg API: Accessing fields for symbol containing fractions

Tags: bloomberg, blpapi

I am using Bloomberg API C# library, version 3.8.10.1.

I am wondering, what is the rule for formatting/escaping fractions in symbol names?
Instruments service (`//blp/instruments`) returns symbols like `RIOLN 3<3/4> 03/22/2022<corp>`, however, querying reference service (`//blp/refdata`) or market data service (`//blp/mktdata`) with:
`RIOLN 3¾ 06/15/2025 Corp`, `RIOLN 3<3/4> 06/15/2025 Corp`, `RIOLN 3 3/4 06/15/2025 Corp` gets me `Unknown/Invalid security [nid:810]` error.

Namely, any modification of such symbol I can think of, gets me this error. Are there any rules for proper formatting of those symbol name fractions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "ASCII" ticker: `EJ101044 Corp`.

You can find it on a terminal by loading the bond and typing `FLDS PARSE`.

Or you can use a different identifier (such as CUSIP or Bloomberg Unique ID).